# migrating a whole application from simple Java to Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have one simple application running on simple Java code.
There is one server which takes data from client and just prints it back.

Now i want to move this application to Spring MVC so that my server will be running 24*7 and any client can be instantiated from web.

So what are the changes i will need to do ??
if required can explain in detail and also post code.

Comment: Hm, just migrating to Spring will not provide 24*7 availability. You use an application server today, or is it a Java SE application only?

Comment: @home: its like i have to prepare a project so its not professional.

Answer (score 0):

Start by getting the Spring Tool Suite and use that for your IDE. It's been a great help, since it comes with project templates, like MVC, that you can basically just plug your existing code into (assuming your code is already written in a way that can be used by other applications).

Once you have a basic MVC project, you can slowly add in your own code.

For more complete examples of Spring MVC form applications, the Spring Security project has a number of good samples. The important parts for you will be the methods inside the controllers that deal with form input, and you can ignore the security stuff for your application.