# Spring MVC tutorial from the scratch

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am quite new to spring coding..
I asked a question earlier but no one replied so I am asking it the other way..!!
I need to move my application from simple Java to Spring MVC.

Is there any good Spring MVC **tutorials that gives info from scratch**??

My simple code is below.

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream (
            m_connection.getInputStream() );

        PrintStream pout = new PrintStream (
            m_connection.getOutputStream() );

        // Read line from client
        String data = din.readLine();

        // Check to see if we should simulate a stalled server
        if (shallWeStall)
        {
            // Yes .. so reset flag and stall
            shallWeStall = false;

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie ) {}
        }
        else
        {
            // No.... but we will next time
            shallWeStall = true;
        }

        // Echo data back to clinet
        pout.println (data);

        // Close connection
        m_connection.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        System.err.println ("I/O error");
    }
}
```

I tried googling, but everything I found was too tough to start from.

Comment: Before continuing: it might be considered more polite to edit the original question rather than create a duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025062/migrating-a-whole-application-from-simple-java-to-spring-mvc.

Comment: @aleksi: sure will take care from next time..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Due to amazing effort by the Spring team links posted here stands as sort of outdated.
I will advice anyone looking to learn spring from scratch to head over to [new awesome guides](http://spring.io/guides) created by spring team.

Sample codes for the same can be found at [Github](http://www.github.com/spring-guides)

**Original Answer :**

try these links.. hope they are useful.
[mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-tutorials/) and [vanilla](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html)

and ofcourse [Spring's own site](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

**ADDED** :
found this new awesome [blog](http://earldouglas.com/publications/barebones-spring-mvc/) do try this also..
its thorough.
:)

Comment: Thanks. That vanilla link was very helpful!

Comment: @nico huysamen : welcome.! :)

Comment: The vanilla tutorial appears to be out of date: it uses Spring 2.5, and the entire paradigm they use seems to have been deprecated in version 3 in favor of annotation-based controllers

Comment: Agreed, but when you are learning from zero a li'l helpful..!!

Answer (score 6):

hey i also found one new excellent site you can use that one too..

[krams tutorials](http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html)

Hope its helpful..
:)

Answer (score 3):

I started learning Spring MVC using this tutorial: [Spring MVC](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework.html). It explains some of the basic concepts well and is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

This [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/) explains basic concepts and provide step by step explanation for implementation.
I started with this one and it really helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260552/getting-started-with-spring-3-web-mvc-setting-everything-up) with some very good answers.

In other words, if you're ok with Spring 2.5, try the [Step-by-Step tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) from SpringSource. If you like Maven, Appfuse has some [great archetypes](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) that get you started with Spring 3 Web MVC.

Comment: thanks.
actually i just need spring thats all..!!

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, If you want to learn something about Spring MVC from scratch then, here is an informative blog published on Spring MVC & MongoDB http://findnerd.com/list/view/Spring-MVC-and-MongoDB/2240/, hope this will help you to understand the Spring MVC in a detailed way.

While learning from this blog you can also post & view  [java questions and answers](http://findnerd.com/askquestion/java) to enhance your tech knowledge among the developers community.

Answer (score 0):

This one uses Spring 3.2, doing all the mapping and configuration with Annotations, and managing the dependencies with Maven:

http://siempredesdeelcurro.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/tutorial-crear-app-web-con-spring-mvc.html

By the way, it's in Spanish, but even if you don't know any word, you can get the code and check the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Start learning with [spring mvc](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/Spring-mvc-hello-world-example.htm) hello world example with java based configuration

Official [Spring 4.3 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)