# Spring 4 MVC/REST annotation config from scratch, without using build tools

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Requesting you to read the description before marking this as a duplicate. Referred questions and sites:

1. [Developing a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step](https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

2. [Spring MVC tutorial from the scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025425/spring-mvc-tutorial-from-the-scratch) and the guides suggested in the answer.

Hello all, I am just starting with Spring 4 MVC and am trying to find a tutorial where I can start building a project from scratch, without using a build tool like Maven or Gradle. I found a few for Spring using XML config, but none so far for annotation config. How the XML config works, I am perfectly clear. But not so much about Annotation config.

My aim is to learn all requisite details regarding setting up and running a Spring 4 MVC project with annotation config, so in the hypothetical event that build tools are not at my disposal, I could still start with and run a Spring MVC project. I have currently succeeded in identifying the minimum dependent JARs required to start a project. I have further questions, few of which are listed below:

Background: I have a Maven project up and running, which has no `web.xml` and `servlet.xml` in its directory structure. This has prompted the following questions:

1. Are `web.xml` and `xyz-servlet.xml` entirely optional when using annotations? 
2. I highly doubt web.xml is optional, so is Maven taking care of it for me in some way?

3. How is the gap created by the missing `xyz-servlet.xml` filled when using annotation config?

4. My start-from-scratch REST project is starting up successfully (I assume), then why do I keep getting a `no mapping found for URI` error when accessing paths?

I tried referring guides and questions (as mentioned in the start), but the 101 guides either use XML config, or use build tools (e.g. Gradle/Maven in the official guide) for Annotation config.

Also, please note: **No Spring Boot, please!**

P.S.: If anyone is interested in answering question #4, I can add the source code and server log. Just give me a heads-up in the comments.

Comment: Ya like xml.. don't you?

Comment: @Joanna No. I prefer annotations.

Comment: I asked because you said "No Spring Boot, please!".. I am wondering why would somebody say no to one of the best things that happened in Java (Micro)services world.

Comment: @Joanna Coz I believe using Boot (& tools like Maven) provides an excuse to developers to deprive themselves of that knowledge. Something I like to summarize as "If I don't have to code it, I don't have to know it". Hence my pursuit of a from-scratch annotation config project without Maven. And to change my prev answer, I actually would prefer XML, bcoz then I am clear about how the execution goes. Just that I find using annotation config is more streamlined and uniform than XML config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be answering my own question since I have figured it out.

1. I have the list of JARs required to initiate a basic, hello-world Spring MVC + Hibernate project. This does not include Jackson or Spring Security et. al, since in my view these are, for the time-being, kind of add-ons.
2. I had to register the servlet in `web.xml` and define a small, simple, straightforward `xyz-servlet.xml` to kick-start the DispatcherServlet. Haven't yet found a way to exclude these as of yet. It's probably something very simple and elementary, I believe, that I am missing.
3. I haven't figured out how for now. As stated above, my current conclusion is it can't be skipped - you need at least a one-liner with `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag. Will explore further.
4. That's because my src folder wasn't added to the Java Resources list in Eclipse.